# what is the negation of ∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) =⇒ (x ∈ nN ∨ y ∈ nN).

Tags: logic, proof-verification

what is the negation of ∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) =⇒ (x ∈ nN ∨ y ∈ nN).

Is this correct?

if the negation of p=>q is p∧~q

then the answer is ∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) ∧ ~(x ∈ nN ∨ y ∈ nN)

= ∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) ∧ ~(x ∈ nN ∨ y ∈ nN)

= ∀x∀y(xy ∈ nN) ∧ (x ∉ nN ∧ y ∉ nN)

is this right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Thank you Mr ALLEGRANZA :)
You help me a lot! let me +rep you!

Comment: But you have to consider if the formula is correctly written; I think that ot makes little sense written as it is. I think that it must be : $∀x∀y[(xy ∈ N) ⇒ (x ∈ N ∨ y ∈ N)]$, in which case you have to consider also the quantifiers.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to maths so I don't understand :"(

Comment: if we consider the formula $∀x∀y[(xy∈N)⇒(x∈N∨y∈N)]$, then its negation will be : $\lnot ∀x∀y[(xy∈N)⇒(x∈N∨y∈N)]$, i.e.  $\exists x \exists y \lnot [(xy∈N)⇒(x∈N∨y∈N)]$, i.e. $\exists x \exists y[(xy ∈ N) ∧ (x ∉ N ∧ y ∉ N)]$.

Comment: oh I see I see
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct:

$$\begin{align} \neg(∀x∀y((xy ∈ \mathbb{N}) ⇒ (x ∈ \mathbb{N} ∨ y ∈ \mathbb{N}))) & \equiv ∀x∀y((xy ∈ \mathbb{N}) \wedge \neg (x ∈ \mathbb{N} ∨ y ∈ \mathbb{N})) \tag{1} \\  
&\equiv ∀x∀y((xy ∈ \mathbb{N}) \wedge (x \notin \mathbb{N} \wedge y \notin \mathbb{N}))   \tag{2}  \\
\end{align}$$
Good work!

Comment: @hchenn Mauro is correct about the brackets: as I wrote [somewhere else](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973747/showing-a-set-is-a-subset-of-another-set), "is always a good practice not omitting parenthesis when your statement starts getting longer (it avoids ambiguity and makes explicit the unique parsing of a formula).". You are doing fine, keep woking hard!